# Can I call a .java file from a .html file with href or something else without using javascript in-between

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I want to call a java file(java class) from index.html using href without using java-script in-between html and java.

I am using springboot and my java file is inside src/main/java/controller and the html is inside src/main/resources/templates.

So anyone please help me to find whether it is possible or not,if yes then how can we achieve that.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: learn basic java first. .java files are not compiled and cannot be run

Comment: Since controllers are exposed, you can implement the `href` so that it refers to a certain controller endpoint. However, without some actual code, this is a fairly broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated from OP comment:

> Thank you very much for your reply and let me correct the question can
>   I call a function which is written in java directly from a html. –
>   JAVA Coder Nov 5 at 9:08

Still the same answer.   Methods or functions, terminology aside.   What you're proposing is like trying to power a bicycle by attaching an engine piston to it without the engine.   Does not compute.

You cannot directly "call" a java process from html/js.

---- END UPDATE

No.

Longer answer:
Java files aren't called. Java classes are. The Java runtime has to live somewhere for java to be used.   Typically that would be in your app server/web server.   Its entirely possible to use java to generate the html, but the way your using the term "call" in this case doesn't make sense.   Html doesn't "call" anything as its really just a rich text implementation (like a painting).  Modern browsers implement javascript interpreters (which has nothing to do the Java) to run javascript code.

So, can you write html to "call" java (without javascript): No.   Can you use java to generate html: Yes.   Can you "call" java from javascript.   Only if its are exposed as a web service (e.g. classes in the app server are configured to present http content)

A programming class and web services overview would probably be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and let me correct the question can I call a function which is written in java directly from a html.

Comment: @JAVACoder you can read up on jsp(jsf) and servlets, or you can write a rest client. But, just to say: Java has methods, not functions.

Comment: Sorry @Stultuske for writing function instead of method as I am  a fresher and just started coding and  seeI don't want to use jsp and javascript I want the communication should be direct.let say I want to put the java method in the src attribute of an audio tag which method will return an audio path which can be played by the audio tag

Comment: @JAVACoder I did not mention JavaScript, did I? Servlets are Java a Rest client is in Java.